# Cannot Execute Org-Babel Haskell Block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In an org-mode file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC haskell
let x = "test"
putStrLn x
#+END_SRC
```

yields:

```
executing Haskell code block...
if: ‘org-babel-script-escape’ expects a string
```

Comment: My guess would be: a mismatch between Haskell mode and Org mode versions. So, I'd try experimenting with different versions of both.

Comment: You don't want `let` in a Haskell babel code block. `let` is for the feeding lines into the REPL one-by-one.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it writing the header argument `:results output` after the declaration of the language in the head of the block source.

> #+BEGIN_SRC haskell :results output

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to comprehend the source code inducing the error, but...

I have same error with `#+BEGIN_SRC haskell`.

However, `#+BEGIN_SRC haskell :results value :eval (inferior-haskell-start-process)` 
works for some reason.

I have

```
haskell-mode       20180601.143  installed
org                9.1.13        installed
```